# Cyclical array in JS

Tags: javascript

I recently read about cyclical array and as far as I understood, it is when we put array in itself. Also, if we then iterate over the cyclical array then we can face infinite loop. Thus, I created this code:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3];
array.push(array); // Creating a cyclic reference

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i];
}
```

I executed the above code but no infinite loop was faced. Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes; you don’t do anything with the array in the loop other than a no-op. For this code to loop infinitely you’d need to iterate over the element if it’s an array.

Answer (score 1):

You're safe here because you don't mutate the array in the loop, put the `push()` inside the loop and you're in a trouble:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array.push(array); // Creating a cyclic reference
}
```

Gives in node:

```html
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 184071938
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffe703d9710
 1: 0xbe67b1  [node]
 2: 0x1e4d4d4 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [node]
 3: 0xf00108  [node]
 4: 0x10afa92  [node]
 5: 0x10afd55  [node]
 6: 0x12beb3b v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
 7: 0x16fb6b9  [node]
```

On the other hand you don't have this trouble because of the cycling reference, you just mutate the array and increase its length. So my guess a proper cycling reference example would be:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];
array.push(array); // Creating a cyclic reference

//here you fall into an infinite recursion thus overflowing the stack
array.flat(Infinity);
```

You can try to flatten the array with any algorithm you like and you'll fall either into an infinite recursion (if recursion is used) or an infinite loop.

So...
Basically my guess is it's nothing extremely bad in using cyclic array when you know what you're doing. Maybe your some smart logic in code needs it. And you don't plan to iterate recursively.
On the other hand you can just easily use a copy of the same array and be safe:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];
array.push(array.slice()); // put a copy and sleep peacefully

console.log(array.flat(Infinity));
```

Comment: thanks, but is there any problem with putting array inside itself leading to Cyclical array. As far I understood, there is no problem. Right?

Comment: The only good part about this answer IMO is the `array.flat` example of how cyclic references can cause infinite recursion. The `push` inside the loop is a different issue unrelated to cyclic references. Copying arrays is slow and doesn't work in general, since mutating the copy won't mutate the original array, which may be desired. The proper solution when you need cyclic arrays is to write your own versions of `flat` etc which can deal with them.

Comment: They’re safe because they don’t do anything with each array element. OP’s code would loop infinitely if it was a recursive iteration.